# Add multiple buttons to WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to add 2-3 buttons to the rows in the last column of my datagrid using the backend C# and not XAML. I managed to add one button to the cells but I'm having trouble adding anymore past that.

I have tried creating a new FrameworkElementFactory and adding it into the column but it just replaces the previous button instead of adding the button.

```
        DataGridTemplateColumn buttonColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        buttonColumn.Header = "Actions";
        buttonColumn.Width = 209;

        DataTemplate buttonTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory buttonFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
        buttonTemplate.VisualTree = buttonFactory;

        buttonFactory.AddHandler(ButtonBase.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Activate));
        buttonFactory.SetValue(ContentProperty, "A");
        buttonColumn.CellTemplate = buttonTemplate;

        dGrid_SavedData.Columns.Add(buttonColumn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether you create it programmatically or in XAML, a `DataTemplate` can only have single root element so you should set the `VisualTree` property to a `FrameworkElementFactory` for a `Panel` and use the `AppendChild` method to add the button factories to the panel factory, e.g.:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn buttonColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
buttonColumn.Header = "Actions";
buttonColumn.Width = 209;

DataTemplate buttonTemplate = new DataTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory panelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
buttonTemplate.VisualTree = panelFactory;

FrameworkElementFactory buttonAFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
buttonAFactory.AddHandler(ButtonBase.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Activate));
buttonAFactory.SetValue(ContentProperty, "A");

FrameworkElementFactory buttonBFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
buttonBFactory.AddHandler(ButtonBase.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Activate));
buttonBFactory.SetValue(ContentProperty, "B");

panelFactory.AppendChild(buttonAFactory);
panelFactory.AppendChild(buttonBFactory);

buttonColumn.CellTemplate = buttonTemplate;

dGrid_SavedData.Columns.Add(buttonColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I’m on an iPad, so I can’t give much detail.  First let me say that this is a very hard way to do this and I recommend just about anything else. But if you absolutely have to fully dynamically generate your grid, you need to put the button in a container.  For example, a vertical stack panel.  Then you can add as many buttons as you want.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the Code Snippet**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgStudent" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" Margin="0,44,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Name="btnDelete" Content="Delete" Click="btnDelete_Click" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```